# exit(); die(); return false;

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what are the differences in die() and exit() in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795025/what-are-the-differences-in-die-and-exit-in-php)

I guess the main question is what is the difference between the 3 exactly?

What is the correct semantic usage for each one of these?

From what I see `return false;` can discontinue a function whereas `die();` and `exit();` will prevent any further code running *at all*.

Is this correct?

Comment: It's been asked before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795025/what-are-the-differences-in-die-and-exit-in-php

Comment: Yep, you have it correct. `return` for functions, `die()/exit()` kill script execution.

Comment: no, that does not include return :))

Comment: @Gigi: I suggest that the other one be closed as a duplicate of this question is slightly broader (since it additionally covers return).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`die()` and `exit()` are precisely identical; they halt the entire PHP program and return to the OS. They're two different names for the same function.

`return`, on the other hand, ends a function call and returns to the caller. At the end of a program, `return` sets the status value that is returned to the OS; the program is going to exit no matter what.

Comment: So what's the need for two functions which do exactly the same thing, there must of been a reason for this.

Comment: Just "syntactic sugar". Perl has `die()`, and many other languages have `exit()`, so by having both, PHP tries to make it easier to transition between languages, I suppose.

Comment: @Brogrammer not quite. Not a significant reason at least. It can be some compatibility issue, a legacy issue, etc. Whatever reason it can be - it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: They're not TWO function indeed, `die` is just an alias to `exit`

Comment: Not correct. `die()` is same as `exit()` but not vice versa. You can pass a param for `exit()`: either `exit(status code number)` or `exit(string status)`, which is passed out from PHP to OS or whatever.

Comment: So, a `return false` will stop the function and if the client presses the function button, the function will start again ?

Comment: @d.sergeiev you can also pass parameters to `die()`, i.e `die("error occurred")` will print "error occurred" before exiting.

Answer (score 11):

According to docs [PHP: exit Manual](http://php.net/manual/function.exit.php) `die()` is an alias to `exit()` so they do the same function and that is to END the script.

The `return` statement ends a function and not the entire script, and returns the value that you choose.