# PHP: What is the difference between exit(), die() and return; within "self" and included files?

Tags: php, return, exit, die

I'm still on a PHP learning curb. When terminating a script, what is the difference between `exit()`, `die();` and `return;`?:

1. within the same file (Single script file)
2. Within the child of an include
3. Within the parent of an include

Comment: exit and die are the exact same thing, and the answer to your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484050/php-exit-or-return-which-is-better

Comment: It's been asked before. See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490731/exit-die-return-false

Comment: @Supericy Yes and no. No, because if you care to pay attention to my detailed points, I want to know the effect these have on includes as well as other things

Comment: @Supericy Essentially they might look the same, but I am asking different things

Comment: @Omar Die and exit are indentical, die is just an alias for exit. The link I gave you answers your question. Exit halts *all* execution. A global return will halt the current script and return to the calling script (if there is one).

Comment: @Supericy So, what are the cause/effect & difference of adding it if I am in a 2, 3, for level of includes and anything in between? -I am sure that if I am coding to include php1 to include php2 to include php3, etc, and somewhere in a function/etc I add (die/exit/return) in either of the php files, there's a difference. One will halt everything all the way to the parent and one will only halt the current one, etc...

Comment: @Supericy Again, this question is more about its effect within DIFFERENT LEVELS of includes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Return returns a value. This can be anything and is meant for functions.

[What are the differences in die() and exit() in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795025/what-are-the-differences-in-die-and-exit-in-php)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: For what I read at http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php, return can also halt the execution of an included script file: "...return will also end the execution of...script file."

Comment: Quote: return, on the other hand, ends a function call and returns to the caller. At the end of a program, return sets the status value that is returned to the OS; the program is going to exit no matter what.

Comment: As of PHP 7.1.0, return statements without an argument trigger E_COMPILE_ERROR, unless the return type is void, in which case return statements with an argument trigger that error.

Answer (score 7):

### [`die`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) and [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) ([equivalent functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795025/what-are-the-differences-in-die-and-exit-in-php/27851270#27851270))

> Terminates execution of the script.

### [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

> Returns program control to the calling module. Execution resumes at
>   the statement following the called module's invocation.
>
> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an
>   eval() statement or script file.
>
> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script
>   file is ended. If the current script file was included or required,
>   then control is passed back to the calling file. Furthermore, if the
>   current script file was included, then the value given to return will
>   be returned as the value of the include call. If return is called from
>   within the main script file, then script execution ends. If the
>   current script file was named by the auto_prepend_file or
>   auto_append_file configuration options in php.ini, then that script
>   file's execution is ended.

---

## [`die`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) vs [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

The difference between [`die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) and [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) in PHP is their **origin**.

- [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) is from [`exit()` in **C**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit).
- [`die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) is from [`die` in **Perl**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html).

---

### PHP Manual

PHP Manual for [`die`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php):

> This language construct is equivalent to [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

PHP Manual for [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php):

> Note: This language construct is equivalent to [`die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php).

PHP Manual for [List of Function Aliases](http://php.net/manual/en/aliases.php):

> [`die`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) is an alias for master function [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

---

## DIFFERENT IN OTHER LANGUAGES

[`die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) and [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) are **different in other languages** but in PHP they are identical.

From [Yet another PHP rant](http://www.beastwithin.org/users/wwwwolf/code/phprant.html):

> ...As a C and Perl coder, I was ready to answer, "Why, exit() just bails
>   off the program with a numeric exit status, while die() prints out the
>   error message to stderr and exits with EXIT_FAILURE status." But then
>   I remembered we're in messy-syntax-land of PHP.
>
> In PHP, exit() and die() are identical.
>
> The designers obviously thought "Hmm, let's borrow [exit() from C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit). And Perl
>   folks probably will like it if we take [die() as is from Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) too.
>   Oops! We have two exit functions now! Let's make it so that they both
>   can take a string or integer as an argument and make them identical!"
>
> The end result is that this didn't really make things any "easier",
>   just more confusing. C and Perl coders will continue to use exit() to
>   toss an integer exit value only, and die() to toss an error message
>   and exit with a failure. Newbies and PHP-as-a-first-language people
>   will probably wonder "umm, two exit functions, which one should I
>   use?" The manual doesn't explain why there's exit() and die().
>
> In general, PHP has a lot of weird redundancy like this - it tries to
>   be friendly to people who come from different language backgrounds,
>   but while doing so, it creates confusing redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

Return is returns a value (char,int,string,array...) and  exit from function.

**From php manual :**

> Note: This language construct is equivalent to die().

But still there are difference between **die** and **exit** :

> Using die() you can post a string : die("An error occurred");

Same result with using exit()

```
<?php
    echo("An error occurred <br>");
    exit(0);
?>
```

**OR if you are cli or unix shell :**

Using PHP on the command line, die("An error occurred") simply prints "An error occurred" to STDOUT and terminates the program with a normal exit code of 0.

```
<?php
    fwrite(STDERR, "An error occurred \n");
    exit(0); //
?>
```