# PHP: Utilizing exit(); or die(); after header("Location: ");

Tags: php, exit, die

I have a user login/registration system that simply uses

```
// execute queries, set cookies, etc. here
header("Location: " . getenv("HTTP_REFERER"));
```

I recently read a post about `exit();` and `die();` and had no idea that I was supposed to be using these. From what I understand, they make it end the PHP? Is that correct? What's the best way I can work toward this, simply adding one of these functions directly after ever header(); execution I have?

I have AJAX, jQuery reading through my login.php/register.php, will this be affect in any way?

Edit: Other than after header();, where else should I be usitilizing the `exit();` or `die();` functions? And is `exit();` more used around PHP whereas `die();` more used around Perl?

Comment: What do you mean by 'AJAX reading through your register.php'? Can you post some code?

Comment: My register.php checks if a form was submitted to it, then reads through the inputs, and using AJAX $.post(); it returns any errors found in register.php into the HTML for the user to see.

Comment: It doesn't particularly matter if you use `die` or `exit` as long as you use one of them.

Comment: I tend to use exit when it's part of a normal script behavior and die when debugging. I have seen others use this convention too. They do the same thing, but the convention is useful.

Comment: I like one-liners so `die(header("location: {$url}"));`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have been looking for an answer on this as well. What I found:

### Why die() or exit():

If you don't put a die() or exit() after your `header('Location: http://something')` your script may continue resulting in unexpected behaviour. This may for example result in content being disclosed that you actually wanted to prevent with the redirect (HTTP 301). The aforementioned may not directly be visible for an end user as the browser may not render it (due to the 301). Conclusion, the exit() and die() functions stop the script from continuing.

### Difference:

I also wanted to know the difference between the functions as it **seems** there is none.  However, in PHP, there is a distinct difference in Header output.
In the examples below I chose to use a different header but for sake of showing the difference between exit() and die() that doesn't matter.

#### Exit() in action

```
<?php
    header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
    exit();
?>
```

Results in:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 
Connection: Keep-Alive 
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
```

#### Die() in action

```
<?php
    header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
    die();
?>
```

Results in:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 
Connection: close
```

#### Difference

So, **die()** closes the connection and **exit()** doesn't. It depends on performance whether or not you want to keep the connection open or close it. Both have advantages and disadvantages and depends on your specific requirement(s).

[HTTP persistent connections on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)

Comment: My HTTP knowledge is a bit hazy at this stage of the semester - when we pull a 301, the browser will (usually; i.e. a correct spec one) close the connection and open another get request, will it not? Or will it use the existing connection to request again?

Comment: You can also join it with `exit(header('Location: xxxxx.php'));`

Comment: [exit and die are identical](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/5hdtkc/seven_syntax_you_can_choose_in_php/dazk1k1/)

Comment: Just tested it and `exit` and `die` work the same way, they both close connection.

Comment: Downvoted, since `die` and `exit` truly *are* identical.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php
Die() is equivalent to exit(). Does it close connection or not, depends on other conditions.

Answer (score 11):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

This functions are used to interrupt script execution. You *need* to use `exit` or `die` to stop execution of your script after `header("Location: " . getenv("HTTP_REFERER"));`, because, in other case, your script will be executed till the end, what can cause some unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Answer has already been accepted however it seems everyone is missing the glaring WTF in the question:

```
header("Location: " . getenv("HTTP_REFERER"));
```

1. Returning a referer is optional on the part of the user agent
2. it can easily be faked
3. there is no method for telling the user the login has failed
4. there is no HTTP semantic communication of an authentication failure
5. while the environment variable HTTP_REFERER should be the same as the request header variable, it is not specified in RFC 3875, therefore even where presented to the webserver in the request, getenv("HTTP_REFERER") may return a different value

Comment: In my login.php I have it check if a user has successfully logged in with proper credentials - if so it will set a cookie - then header("Location"); to the referral page. In this way, no matter where they are on the site, when the logon, it will take them back to the page they logged in at instead of taking them to the main page or login.php. Is there a better method than this then?

Comment: Drop a cookie with the intended page URL before rendering the login page, or pass the URL as a $_GET var, or store the intended URL in the session

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it has been a long time since the last answer was given. Anyway :D somehow I stumbled across a similar prob and see what my solution was:

```
die( Header( "Location: mytarget.php?arg1=foobar" ) );
```

Two birds with one stone - seems to work for me.

Comment: This will keep return value from `header()` function in a temporary variable, which is passed to `die()`. It works, because the return value from `header()` is always `null`. 

Another difference is that it doesn't allow debuggers to create breakpoints between `die()` and `header()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    if ($i == 2)
    {
        exit("\n Using exit(), We are done");
    }
}
```

Now let us look at the same example using die();

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    if ($i == 2)
    {
        die("\n Using die(), We are done");
    }
}
```

The output for each of these will be: “Using exit(), We are done Using die(), We are done” respectively. Now let us try each of these to output a number.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    if ($i == 2)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Looking at the output for the same example using die();

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    if ($i == 2)
    {
        die(-1);
    }
}
```

These examples were edited using a textpad editor. The output for both the above cases were “Tool completed with exit code -1”.

So, the honest answer to the question “What is difference between die() and exit() in php” IS – There is not a single visible difference between these two functions. They both are the same, one is the alias of the other. If at all any one of you can find a real visible difference then I would appreciate if you could post it in the comments section of this blog.

Answer (score -2):

When `header()` is called at the end of a script, there's no need to call `exit()`, nor `die()` since:

> The link to the server will be closed as soon as the execution of the script ends, unless it's closed earlier by explicitly calling mysql_close(). - [*php.net/function.mysql-connect*](https://secure.php.net/function.mysql-connect)

Comment: It's absolutely crucial to `exit` or `die` after sending a _Location_ header, since you cannot guarantee that your header will actually be respected. [Have a good read about what can go wrong.](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction)

Comment: The problem with not exiting after issuing a Location header is that the script may execute more statements that the engineer does not expect. The script may be terminated by the web server based on the browser stopping the page load, but that cannot be relied upon.