# HTTP connection resets after calling die() or exit() somewhere after RPC AMQP call

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I have some kind of internal API which works with a DB and I'm doing calls to this API via AMQP. And when I do a synchronous (RPC) call and after that trying to redirect then HTTP connection resets.
I'm redirecting like this:

header("Location: some_url");
die;

And I've found that the problem is in die() function. So I'm using PHP5.3, Apache2, RabbitMQ as AMQP broker. Also I'm using this extension http://pecl.php.net/package/amqp to work with AMQP. This is very confusing because if I remove die() everything is fine with the connection. But it's impossible to remove it because [PHP: Utilizing exit(); or die(); after header("Location: ");](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665985/php-utilizing-exit-or-die-after-headerlocation)

I will really appreciate if somebody can give me clue. Thanks

Comment: try http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php before die

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) before `die()`.