# PHP which is the best practise of header location

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

I have a confusion in using `PHP` `header location`. which way is best practice...?

```
if(true){
    header("location:somepage.php");
}
```

or

```
if(true){
    header("location:somepage.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: The second one is correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665985/php-utilizing-exit-or-die-after-headerlocation/23061178.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sending the `Location:' header PHP *will* continue parsing, and all code below the header() call will still be executed.  So instead use your second example:

```
if(true){
       header("location:somepage.php");
       exit;
  }
```

Comment: Even tho best practice is properly writing the headers: `header("Location: somepage.php");`

Comment: If the PHP code ends immediately after, there is no need to `exit()` see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665985/php-utilizing-exit-or-die-after-headerlocation/23061178#23061178).

Answer (score 2):

Headers will continue to be sent after an initial header is sent - so if you really, really mean it - you can end the script with an `exit;`.

The catch however is that you might still want to execute script after the user is redirected to another page - so you don't actually want to put in an `exit;`.

Example of good code:

```
header("location:somepage.php");
//continue code and do stuff.
```

Example of bad code:

```
header("location:somepage.php");
// Continue code and do other stuff... then...
header("location:somepageOtherPage.php");
// This is the header that the user will get.
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely I would go with the 2nd Option. Otherwise the script execution is not terminated. Setting another header alone is not enough to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

it depends what you want to do:
if you want the rest of script to still run after changing the header - use the first option (without the exit() ).
if (more likely) you don't want the script to continue - use the second option (with the exit() )

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you do not use "exit" the rest of your script will be executed before the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

header() with exit() statement is a good practice. If you don't write exit() it will execute the some statements after the redirection cause problems. exit() will stop all the further execution.

```
header("location:somepage.php");
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct because the page will automatically redirected to the page where you specified inside header syntax.So exit is not needed.