# Best practices for using PHP's exit from FastCGI

Tags: php, apache, nginx, cgi, fastcgi

I ran across some code using `exit` to abort process a request as soon as an error was encountered. I'm not a PHP expert, but my immediate reaction, knowing FastCGI at a high level, is that would exit the process and is generally a bad idea. This wasn't the case with Nginx and my current PHP, but with ancient Apache versions, [this was a problem](http://www.fastcgi.com/om_archive/mail-archive/0224.html). PHP's documentation on FastCGI was [pretty sparse](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fpm.php), but it did mention `fastcgi_finish_request` which looks like a graceful way to finish the request.

The documentation for `exit` is unclear on whether it has any performance implications for FastCGI, but there is the subtle distinction that it exists the *script*, not the process. The documentation for [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) actually uses `exit`, and I found the pattern in [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header) [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747791/why-i-have-to-call-exit-after-redirection-through-headerlocation-in-php) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665985/php-utilizing-exit-or-die-after-headerlocation]), but the justification was "so you don't send a body," not "if you don't emit a body after the header, the body will be empty and the redirect will work as expected."

I also found [conflicting answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/84962/php-via-fastcgi-terminated-by-calling-exit) on whether or not it causes problems. That, and [Dreamhost recommends against `exit` when using FastCGI](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/FastCGI#No_Exits) (though their example's in Perl). The one place it definitely causes problems is unit testing.

So my question: what's the best practice for using `exit` in PHP web pages? Is `fastcgi_finish_request` a better choice? Would restructuring the control flow be better? Are the problems people reported Apache-specific? Or is this just another version of "are multiple `returns` bad programming practice?"

Comment: "Would restructuring the control flow be better? " yes; exit is lazy.

Answer (score 0):

1, first, you should use php-fpm, not the old fastcgi module.
2, the [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) in php doesn't mean exit the current process. The doc already says, especially when php running in a fastcgi server. It just abort the intepretor session. The process goes on and pick another http request from nginx/apache connection pool and php-fpm call the engine again.