# In Laravel 5.1 when I send header Content-type to download a file, do I have to put die() at the end?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

This is my helper

```
function fileDownload(EloquentFile $file, bool $stream): bool {

    $file_dir = $file->dir . '/';
    $file_url = $file_dir . $file->id;

    $stream = $stream === true ? 'attachment' : 'inline';

    if (Storage::disk('s3')->has($file_url)) {
        header('Content-type: ' . $file->mime);
        header('Content-Disposition: ' . $stream . '; filename=' . $file->name);
        header('Content-Length: ' . $file->size);
        echo Storage::disk('s3')->get($file_url);

        //die(); do I have to put die here?
    }

    abort(404);
}
```

Question - does commented `die()` is required here or can I skip it?

Comment: well, if output buffering is enabled, and you DON'T exit, then you proceed on to the `abort(404)`, whi then causes your download page to say "not found", AND send out the download data. confusing, to say the lease. "couldn't find what you wanted, but here's what you wanted anyways"

Comment: Use a return statement instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Utilizing exit(); or die(); after header("Location: ");](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665985/php-utilizing-exit-or-die-after-headerlocation)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#file-downloads

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest against using any die or exit statements and just directly return the response.

For your example it would be

```
return Storage::disk('s3')->get($file_url);
```