# empty($_GET['variable']) blocks the script when the variable has no value

Tags: php, get, isset, is-empty

I am writing quite a simple script that uses a GET parameter to define a variable in the script. So at the beginning of the script, I check that the GET parameter exists and that it's not empty (to avoid `...page.php?param=`).

I wrote this piece of code (the parameter is named `a`) :

```
if (!isset($_GET['a']) || empty($_GET['a'])) {
    header("Location: https://..."); // redirect to home page
    die();
}
```

And it works when there is no GET parameter at all, but if there is either `?a` or `?a=`, then the page is just blank, even though I add an `echo "some text";`

I don't really understand what is going on. Could someone explain it to me?

Thank you :-)

EDIT : here is the whole code page:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['a']) || trim($_GET['a']) == '' || $_GET['a'] == NULL) {
    header("Location: https://google.com");
    exit();
}

echo "hello";
```

So I should either redirect to Google.com or print "hello" but none of this happens.

Comment: Could you add the code of the page with the `echo "some text";`?

Comment: You need to use `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: Instead of `die();`, use `exit();` after `header(...);` function call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Utilizing exit(); or die(); after header("Location: ");](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665985/php-utilizing-exit-or-die-after-headerlocation)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I replaced `die();` with `exit();`. No change in the behaviour. Also, my post is not a duplicate I think, because my question is about `empty();` rather than `die();`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul `die` and `exit` are *almost* the same thing. It doesn't matter. The differences are slight and not part of this problem.

Comment: *the page is just blank* means something is broken. Add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: @Martin The header output will be fairly different for `exit()` and `die()`. *there is a distinct difference in Header output.* is what [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20932511/5517143) said.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul yes, but that answer does not relate to the issues faced in *this* question!

Comment: @Martin You could be right, hence I made a comment and not an answer. Glad that the issue has been resolved. *Cheers!* :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blank page is a classic example of a PHP error. You need to set up and [use PHP error logging facility](http://error_reporting(E_ALL);%20ini_set('display_errors',%201);) like so:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

At the very top of your page.

Rewriting your page I would do this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if (!isset($_GET['a']) || is_null($_GET['a'])) {
    header("Location: https://google.com");
    exit();
}

echo "hello";
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
if (!isset($_GET['a']) || trim($_GET['a']) == "") {
```

check the manual for empty
http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: The manual states that a empty string (`""`) is considered empty and should return `true`. It is what I want, so why not using `empty()`?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
if (!isset($_GET['a']) || trim($_GET['a']) == '' || $_GET['a'] == NULL) {
    header("Location: https://www.google.com"); // redirect to home page
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work and I don't see why `empty` is not OK. Isn't it supposed to check what you asked me to try?

I also added the whole page code in my first post.