# Can't read session variable due login script

Tags: php, session, variables, authentication

Currently I have a problem with setting up a session variable.

```
    <?php

session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
    header("Location: home.php");
}

require 'pdoconnect.php';

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,email,password FROM users WHERE email = :email');
    $records->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $message = '';

    if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password']) ){

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
        header("Location: glogin.php");
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];


    } else {
        $message = 'Login failed, try again';
    }

endif;
```

Above you can see the login script that I'm using, this code is running at

> login.php

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">

<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" name="email" required>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" required>

<input type="submit" value="Log in">

<?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
<p><?= $message ?></p>
<?php endif; ?> 

</form>
```

And this is the form that is used to login, the form is also running at

> login.php

Now the problem comes, I want to put the email that the user used to login into a session variable, but I can't set the form action to a other page because then the login script will not work anymore.

So my question is: 'How do I read $_SESSION['email'] without changing the form action?

I already tried to include login.php into a other page but didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: try to echo $_SESSION['email'] after your if condition, see if it contains any value

Comment: i think u need to use `header("Location: glogin.php");` after `$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];` otherwise it will redirect to gologin page without saving session value

Comment: and i also suggest to use $result value not $_POST value for session as like `id` example: `$_SESSION['email'] = $results['email'];`

Comment: and if you want to read `email` value in other page than you also need to include this function in each page `session_start();`

Answer (score 0):

You are using redirection `header()` before `$_SESSION` value assignment.

**This:**

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
header("Location: glogin.php");
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
```

**Should be:**

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
header("Location: glogin.php"); // at last
exit;
```

If you want to use `$_SESSION['email']`  value in `glogin.php` page than you must need to start your session `session_start()` in page also.

One last suggestion, you can can `$results` value instead of `$_POST` value in your session same as `id` field like:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $results['email'];
```

*You also need to learn why `exit()` required after `header()` function, you can read this post: [PHP: Utilizing exit(); or die(); after header("Location: ");](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665985/php-utilizing-exit-or-die-after-headerlocation)*

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead of login.php as form action.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

You should also `exit` after using `header('Location: ...')`.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

If you do not exit after doing a redirect, the complete script will still be executed. Some variables might not be set and well, in short.. Just `exit;`

Furthermore you are redirecting before setting your session variables.

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
header("Location: glogin.php");
exit;
```

#### Update

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do with gloging.php but it should look something like this.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['email'];
    exit;
} else {
    header("Location: nologin.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: But I still get an error at `glogin.php` that says $results is undefined. I edited the full code as you suggested.

Comment: @Jummy01234: you can access `$results` in glogin file. you can use $_SESSION variable in this file.

Comment: @devpro, this is the code that I'm using now as you said, but it still says $results undefined.

Comment: `<?php 
session_start();
if( (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) ){
 $_SESSION['email'] = $results['email'];
 $email = $_SESSION['email'];
 header('Refresh: 1.5; URL=home.php');
 exit;
}

else {
 header("Location: nologin.php");
 exit;
}

?>`

Comment: @Jummy01234 `$_SESSION['email']` you have already set the email in session in current file no need to assign again. `$email = $_SESSION['email'];` should be `echo $_SESSION['email'];`

Comment: [link](http://txt.do/d5jd5) `login.php` and [link](http://txt.do/d5jdd) `gloging.php`. I did what you suggested, but still $results is undefined

Comment: login.php is fine now.. I'll check gloging.php .. a moment please