# After a PHP_SELF Form Is Submitted, how do I redirect to a new page?

Tags: php, html, form-submit

I have a page that submits a form like this;

```
<form name="getInfoForm" class="getInfoForm" action="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" target="" method="post" novalidate autocomplete="off" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

After the form is processed in the PHP part of the page, how can I redirect to a new page? 
The PHP processes the form and submits the data to a MySQL table. I want to then go to a specific new page. How do I do that?
I can't find an answer in all the similar questions, or I don't understand it.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, apparently I didn't explain this well enough. I understand about using HEADER but I don't know where to put it in my PHP. If I put it at the top of my code or the bottom it apparently launches immediately and takes me to the location specified. The PHP updates a MySQL table, so I need the redirect to happen after the successful INSERT INTO the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect in PHP using the following:

```
header("location: yourpage.php")
```

Where "yourpage.php" is the name/path of the page you wish to redirect to.

It is worth referring to the PHP manual if you wish to learn more about the [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Answer (score 0):

Do your redirect using header() function and also die() right after:

```
    header("location: xxxx");
    die();
```

Read more about why you need die() in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665985/php-utilizing-exit-or-die-after-headerlocation/20932511#20932511)