# allow download using fputcsv but leaving out extra html code in outputted file?

Tags: php, html, fputcsv

In my code I am creating a file with fgetcsv. I download it and open the file but all the html from my page is included with the csv file. Is there anyway I can just have the data I want to output from the file and not the extra html. my function for creating the csv is below

```
function makefile()
{
    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.csv");

    $this->filepointer  =   fopen('php://output', 'a');



    for($count=0;$count < count($this->alldata);$count++)
    {
       fputcsv($this->filepointer, $this->alldata[$count]);
    }

    fclose($this->filepointer);

}
```

also I was wondering if i use $this->filepointer = fopen('file.csv', 'w') will the file still be populated with the html. as I dont have to have the file downloading I was just using it to check if the file was being created in the correct format. thanks again

Comment: this code could not be including html, unless it's part of that `$this->addata`. it's probably your download page being implemented incorrectly, wrapping the file in html.

Comment: Hi, yeah the function is being called on a page with html code on it. "$this->alldata" is an array of arrays. tried echoing it out with var_dump() and It definately only contains useful data, no html etc.

Comment: so if your download page is something like `echo 'html'; echo file_get_contents('yourfile.txt');` then yeah... you'll get html. the download link code path should contain NO output other than whatever's in your file.

Comment: You have to retrieve your desired data from the file or database you want to, you cannot take data just from the html, except if you're doing it with jQuery.

Comment: so basically your saying there should be no other code on the page to get just the array data into the csv file format? that is indeed a balls

Comment: could you clarify that for me? cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995117/fputcsv-inserting-html-code-into-a-csv-file here it is

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code. You need to add read_file at the end after setting some header as below.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['link']))
{
    $var_1 = $_GET['link'];
    $file = $var_1;

if (file_exists($file))
    {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
    }
} //- the missing closing brace
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use  ob_end_clean() ;  before writing the file