# Throw new exception doesn't stop the code

Tags: php

I want to stop code execution (all application code). Actually I manage this code:

```
try
    {
        $connection = mysqli_connect(   $this->_host,
            $this->_username,
            $this->_dbPass,
            $this->_dbName  );

        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            throw new Exception("problem in connection.");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
        echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => $ex->getMessage()));
        return;   //<- application don't end
        //exit(); //<- application end
     }
```

Now if I call another method after the above code block that prints "hello world" with the `return` statement I get the echo, but if I use `exit()` I don't see any echo. So my question is: throw a new exception don't stop the application instance? I must use exit() for stop it after the exception instead of return?

Comment: Or die(); You are just setting the header but you must specify that your code should stop.

Comment: you suggest to use die or exit?

Comment: *Thinking outloud here*: `exit( json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => $ex->getMessage())); );`

Comment: I think die, sound cool too :)

Comment: Do you want a more concise answer than "yes" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795025/what-are-the-differences-in-die-and-exit-in-php

Comment: @Fred-ii- thinking outloud? what?

Comment: `exit();` does accept an argument. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php so not 100% sure if my suggestion would work.

Comment: @SevengamesXoom: Another way of proposing a solution (humor)

Comment: Is this code inside a function?  Why would you expect returning from a function to exit the entire application?

Comment: @KA_lin haha I'm not english so it's difficult for me understand some humor :P

Comment: @David yes is inside a function... anyway I just replaced with die();

Comment: @SevengamesXoom: Well, returning from a function just stops *that function*.  I don't know of any programming language where that would stop *the entire application* from continuing.

Comment: @SevengamesXoom: Additionally, you're making entirely incorrect use of exceptions here.  If you want to perform the logic that's in the `catch` block in the event of a SQL connection error, just put that logic inside of your `if` block.  There's no need for an exception here at all.  As a general rule, never use exceptions for logic flow.

Comment: @David This code is part of RestFul API... so I must stop the execution before of do anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103894/discussion-between-sevengames-xoom-and-david).

Comment: @SevengamesXoom: Those two statements have nothing to do with one another.  But if you want to end the script then, well, you *already know how* in the question itself.  `exit();`  So... what exactly are you asking?  "If I use `exit()` then the script ends.  But if I don't, it doesn't end.  How do I make the script end?"  That makes no sense.

Comment: @David well I thought that with throw automatically the script's die, but I was wrong...

Comment: @SevengamesXoom: If an exception isn't *caught* then it would end the script.  But you explicitly catch the exception in your code.  (And I really can't stress enough how much you *shouldn't* even be using exceptions here.)

Comment: @David yes, but for end the script I must add `die()`

Comment: @SevengamesXoom: Or `exit()`, which you already knew because it's in the code you posted.

Comment: @David yes, I see the difference between `die` and `exit` and are equal I guess, why php use two equal function?

Comment: PHP has a lot of aliases for common functions, mostly to assist people coming from other languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been quite a discussion in the comments, but to answer the question at hand, a return does stop execution of the script in the global scope.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59a49286b1cbb62e92fd95134593c2da5ef94468

Example:

```
<?php

try {
    throw new Exception('Hello');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    return;
}
echo "hello world"; // Not reached

?>
```

An exception will stop execution if it is uncaught.  Otherwise, if the exception is caught, the same rules apply.  In the global scope, return will exit the application, inside a function or method, a return will only exit the function.

`exit()` or `die()` will both exit the application no matter what scope they are called in.

Comment: i removed my own answer because this one is better.