# PHP Try Ask , How to avoid multiple try ask functions

Tags: php, error-handling

im trying to deal with error catches and sending the user to a error page upon any errors , im also trying to make sure that the session is started if it is the first and only apperance at the page the user starts at.

from this code, how could i remove the need to try catch every part of the page. i was thinking along the lines of maybe a universal error catch that sends user to an error page upon any error, along with the error data.

So far iv placed every part of the page in try catch  , but it seems unecessery. am i right in thinking this, or is alot more secure to check every part of the page this way.

Also the Session_start(); is confusing me, Does it only need to be called once, or should it be called whenever it is not set. if thats the case how do i ensure no matter what page the user begins on , the session will be started. when the session is allready started i cannot recall it on everypage. so how do i check if the session has started or not... Currently i am looking for $_SESSION to have been filled, but that may not be the case on all occassions of every page. im just wondering is there another way to check if Session_Started();

is session started set in the users cache??? so if the user came back to the website and bypassed index.php then session would not need to be started. or should i be checking on evvery page for session to be started?

Any help is greatly appreciated, im new and learning as much as i can but often i come across these instances where only human interaction can advise.

```
<div class='MainContainerDiv'> 
        
                    <?php 
                    if (!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}//session_start should only be called once

                        try{
                            $DBConnect='DBmanagment/DBConnect.php';
                            include $DBConnect;
                            }
                            catch(exepetion $e){ 
                                $_SESSION['ConnectionError'] = $e->getMessage();

                                header("location: pages/ERRORS/ERRORPAGE1.php");
                                exit();die();
                            };


                                try{
                                    $selectedpage="pages/landingpage/Landingpage.php";
                                    if (!isset($selectedpage)) {$selectedpage='pages/landingpage/Landingpage.php';} else {$selectedpage=$selectedpage;}

                                    include $selectedpage;
                                    }
                                    catch(exepetion $e){ 
                                        $_SESSION['ConnectionError'] = $e->getMessage();

                                        header("location: pages/ERRORS/ERRORPAGE1.php");
                                        exit(); die();

                                        };
                    


                    ?>
                    
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sesion_start()` can only be called once **per execution**. If you call it more than once, it will show some error message. You can check if the session has been initiated, but the "right" thing to do is to have a clean structure where the database connections, `session_start()` are handled only by one file that is included in all the other pages.

If you don't care about that, you can check the session with:

```php
<?php
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    //session has not started
    session_start();
}
```

About the try/catch thing, **in PHP** if you find yourself making a lot of try/catch, probably you are doing something wrong. I know that in other languages (like Python) is normal to try to include a file and handle the error, but in PHP the common practice is to check if the file exits with an `if` statement and the`file_exists` built-in function. If the file exists, you can include it and if not, you handle the error in the `else` part of your code.

In python the philosophy is: It is better to ask for forgiveness than to ask for permission

While in PHP is: Better safe than sorry.

Comment: thank you, il look into it and ammend my code. i lack the php function knowledge, so im learning as i go along unfortunatly, and im presented with a new set of problems everyday.

Comment: This is a normal part of the process. Just keep working, if you don't find any problem while learning I would say that you are not really trying. Also, if my answer helped you remember to check it as the solution to your question.

Comment: Also exit() die() is redundant

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: What must i use in replace of Die() exit() - i checked here, but its a little inconclusive for me. https://rules.sonarsource.com/php/RSPEC-1799

Comment: Its pretty much the same. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795025/what-are-the-differences-in-die-and-exit-in-php