# Is it possible for someone to somehow turn off being redirected from a PHP webpage to another?

Tags: php, redirect, session-cookies, websecurity

I'm working on a PHP-based website which stores within a session variable whether or not a user is logged in. If they're not logged in, they'll be redirected to a login page.

My concern is that they could somehow turn of being redirected and thus be able to view the page without being logged in.

If this is possible, how would I go around trying to stop that from happening?

I have the redirection code at the top of the page like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION["LoggedIn"])) {
    $_SESSION["LoggedIn"] = false;
    $logginURL = "login.php";
    header("location: " . $logginURL);
    die();
} else {
    if ($_SESSION["LoggedIn"] == true) {
        $homeURL = "home.php";
        header("location: " . $homeURL);
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

**(This code just determines on the index page whether or not they should be taken to a login page or the home page)**

Comment: In theory, someone could instruct their browser through overly complicated ways to ignore the 301/302 redirect. However, the `die` would prevent any additional code from executing, so it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Does that include the html? (Read some documentation on die() and it only really says it kills the script not specifying about the html)

Comment: PHP is executed top-to-bottom. If there's anything _not_ between an opening and closing PHP tag `<?php ?>`, and that is _before_ the `die` or `exit`, it will be sent to the client (unless output buffering is utilized). Any HTML linearly after that `die` (ignoring jumps from functions and such) will not be sent. You can build a quick demo by creating a single page with the following: `<?php die(); ?><h1>Hello</h1>`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force them to be redirected.

```
exit;
```

This prevents further execution after you send the header

Comment: This does the same as the `die()` in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795025/what-are-the-differences-in-die-and-exit-in-php

Comment: Actually, `die()` calls `exit()`, which is an extra unnecessary function call, so for efficiency, exit is superior. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/aliases.php